# Why I Cant see 'Upload Files' button in Mobile?

Tags: community, files

I have a lightning community and I can upload files from the computer:

[image: Web version]

When I enter with the same User from web-browser but from Mobile I cant see the upload button:

[image: Mobile version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce Communities built with lightning template (Customer Portal, Help Center etc…) aren’t  supported by Salesforce Mobile App (both android and Ios).
If you try to access the community throw mobile browser you can find some limitation such as the possibility to Upload File throw the Action in the files Tab or in the related list of any object, in a few words mobile browser view for lightning communities doesn't support upload file action.
For me there are 2 solutions:

1. (standard) Use the chatter post action for a specific object; when you post something related to an object record you can attach a file and after that you can find the file in the related list of the record:

   [image: Add image on chatter Post]
2. (custom) Use a custom lightning component as action that allow the upload and attach of a file to a record and add it to the page layout (Es: you can use the "[fileupload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation)" standard component)